# Spark: Group by Key and filter the record based on condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've the below spark dataset and I'm trying to pick only one row after grouping by "id" column. If there is only one record, keep the record as is. if there are 2 records for the key, then use the below condition to pick. If there are 2 records and the condition fail, choose anyone.

```
(released == true && hold_reason = "") or (released == false && hold_reason != "")
```

I'm not able to proceed forward since I'm new to spark Dataset API. It'd be great if someone can show me the right direction to proceed.

Input Data:

```
+---+------+--------+-----------+
| id| nt_id|released|hold_reason|
+---+------+--------+-----------+
|id1|nt_id1|    true|           |
|id2|nt_id2|   false|    Blocked|
|id3|nt_id3|   false|           |
|id3|nt_id3|    true|  whitelist|
|id5|nt_id4|    true|  whitelist|
|id6|nt_id6|   false|           |
+---+------+--------+-----------+
```

Output Data:

```
+---+------+--------+-----------+
| id| nt_id|released|hold_reason|
+---+------+--------+-----------+
|id1|nt_id1|    true|           |
|id2|nt_id2|   false|    Blocked|
|id3|nt_id3|   true |           |
|id5|nt_id4|    true|  whitelist|
|id6|nt_id6|   false|           |
+---+------+--------+-----------+
```

```
val ds = 
Seq(Person("id1","nt_id1",true, ""),
Person("id2","nt_id2",false, "Blocked"),
Person("id3","nt_id3",false, ""), 
Person("id3","nt_id3",true, "whitelist"), 
Person("id5","nt_id4",true, "whitelist"), 
Person("id6","nt_id6",false, "")).toDS()
```

Comment: your condition doesn't make any sense `(released == true && hold_reason = "") or (released == false && hold_reason != "")`, Or do you mean released1 and released2. after grouping? I think its better to add few more example for condition to understand.